# Delete Record in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I'm having a problem with my delete command. No error, but when I run, the query says:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider+SingleResult`1[WindowsApplication1.StoredProcedure3Result]' to data type int.*

This is my code:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(
  "server=IAI-004;uid=admin;pwd=intelassist;database=payroll")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
conn.Open()

cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM employee_info WHERE employee_id ='" &
                  DataGridView1.DataSource.ToString & "'"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

I think the problem is :

```
employee_id ='" & DataGridView1.DataSource.ToString & "'"
```

which is a string. And my `employee_id` data type is Integer.

Do I need to convert it? If not, what is the possible solution for this?

Comment: if the EmpID is displayed in the grid, pass that as the SQL param.  you are passing the datasource as the ID which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the single quotes:

Also, DataGridView1.DataSource.ToString is NOT going to get you the employee_id

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM employee_info WHERE employee_id =" &  DataGridView1.DataSource.ToString
```

Comment: not going to get? so you mean it is wrong? do you have any idea to get the emp_id pls?

Answer (score 0):

declare the specific row then loop for delete query .

```
    Dim Emp_ID As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
     Emp_ID = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value()   


    query = "DELETE FROM employee_info WHERE employee_id = '" + Emp_ID + "'"


            mysql_connect(True)
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
            cmd.Connection = SQLConnection
            cmd.CommandText = query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


Next
  MsgBox("Deleted")
```